# Metro Framework and C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, metroframework

can someone explain how can I fix it...

I use Metro Framework downloaded from GitHub and when I use two metro tile I get form like on image bellow.

[image: My example Metro Form]

But I want when click on "Theme" or "Color" to change like default. You can see on top not change color and window not change to dark theme but only metro text box, metro label but metro panel it's OK.

```
private void metroTileSwitch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var m = new Random();
    int next = m.Next(0, 13);
    metroStyleManager.Style = (MetroColorStyle)next;
}
private void metroTile1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    metroStyleManager.Theme = metroStyleManager.Theme == MetroThemeStyle.Light ? MetroThemeStyle.Dark : MetroThemeStyle.Light;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: It is important with any "framework" that does not have enough documentation to study the demo code.  If you don't then you'll very quickly get stuck like this and you'll post the completely wrong snippet.  Crystal ball says you used a plain Form instead of a MetroForm as the base class.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author on Github, by opening an issue?

Comment: You are changing the theme of the page, that little line at the top is the Style of the form. As it was said above me there is little to no documentation with the framework so you need to tool around with it a bit to figure these things out.

Answer (score 1):

**Be sure of that :**

step 1- items that doesn't change theme , theme property is set to `Default` example:

```
     this.Theme = MetroThemeStyle.Default;
```

step 2- set owner of `metroStyleManager` to this form :

```
     metroStyleManager1.Owner = this;
```

step 3- ***if problem still*** you need to connect each item to `metroStyleManager` example :

```
     this.StyleManager = metroStyleManager1;
     metroTextBox1.StyleManager = metroStyleManager1;
     //etc...
```